# Card display in parallel

Tags: css, layout

I am new to frontend. I have four cards arranged in two rows. I want to align these in such a way that next card covers the space of other. I have tried multiple ways but it either aligns to the bottom of top cards in a row or to top. Check the image below to what I want to achieve.
[image: Four squares in a masonry layout: the overall height of each column is the same but the height of the individual squares differs.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
.lefttop { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.leftbottom { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 2; }
.righttop { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.rightbottom { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 5 / 3; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item lefttop"></div>
  <div class="item leftbottom"></div>
  <div class="item righttop"></div>
  <div class="item rightbottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works like charm. Is there a way I get it working using material lite design components. I can't use custom grid only the designs available in https://getmdl.io/components/

Comment: thanks very much for your detailed response. I will try to workaround using material lite. I accepted your response.

Comment: @Aatiya please note that you can only accept *one* answer, make sure you accept only one best answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best method to achieve this look is to use Flexbox and set `flex-direction: column`. Then you could set `flex-wrap: wrap` and then finally put an absolute height on the parent element.